Is the OED now available for free online?
https://www.oed.com/
seems to be totally free.  Is there a catch like "you have used all you free searches" after which the website asks for a subscription?

OED isn't free; or at least, they don't make everything available.
The "factsheet" tab is generally available, but other tabs may not be. For example, without logging in I can't get very far with enthuse.
Some words do have complete information available free. Today's Word of the Day is ramgunschoch and that does have full information available for free. It's possible that previous Words of the Day remain free too, and some other words may not require a login either.
Other Oxford dictionaries, for example the Oxford Learners' Dictionary do offer more complete information freely.

You can obtain a free subscription through your library, at least in the UK. You need to go to a library and provide a proof of address. Then they give you a library card. You can register with the name of your library and the number on your library card.
